# Create virtual table filtering with dynamic measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

My original table of data is the following:

```
TableA

Lot Date
A   01/01/2022
B   10/06/2022
C   01/12/2022
```

I create a second table:

`TableB = 'TableA'`, the date of this second table is referenced to the slicer.

In the slicer I select for example date range from 01/06/2022 to 31/06/2022.

TableB now looks like:

```
Lot Date
B   10/06/2022
```

I have two measures that I want them to select the two date values of the slicer:

```
MinValueSlicer = min(TableB[Date])

MaxValueSlicer = max(TableB[Date])
```

Is this correct?

Now I have a third table, TableC. I want Table C to show the rows of TableA that have Date > MaxDateSlicer

Like this:

```
Lot Date
C   01/12/2022
```

For this I create:

```
TableC= SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('TableA','TableA'[Date]>MaxSlicerDate),"LOT",[LOT],"Date",[Date])
```

For some reason this is not working.

Comment: TableA and TableB are same you said. There will no dates greater than MaxSlicerDate. Thats why its not giving any output

Comment: TableA and TableB are the same before applying the slicer filter, once i filter TableB there are some results before and some resutls after

Comment: Slicers can not have any effect on calculated tables in your data model. They only apply to measures.